# Setting up SVNKit when multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, svnkit

I'm trying to connect to many SVN repositories in parallel, using different threads, with SVNKit.

Looking at some code examples online, it looks like before using SVNKit I have to initialize it using the static methods

```
DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();
FSRepositoryFactory.setup();
```

Obviously static methods make me concerned in a multithreaded environment. My question is:

1. Is it possible to use SVNKit this way, in parallel?
2. When do I need to call these setup methods? Only at the beginning of the software, once for each thread, what?

I would also be glad if someone could explain the reason I have to call these methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to call this method once, before creating repository instances in your different threads.

From SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl javadoc:

> do it once in your application prior to using the library enables working with a repository via the svn-protocol (over svn and svn+ssh)

Here is an example code with 2 repositories (monothread) :

```
SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup(); // ONCE!

String url1 = "svn://host1/path1";
SVNRepository repository1 = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url1));
String url2 = "svn://host2/path2";
SVNRepository repository2 = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url2));
```

In multithread environment, you can create a class implementing Runnable:

```
public class ProcessSVN implements Runnable {

    private String url;

    public ProcessSVN(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void run() {
        SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
        // do stuff with repository
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup(); // STILL ONCE!

(new Thread(new ProcessSVN("http://svnurl1"))).start();
(new Thread(new ProcessSVN("http://svnurl2"))).start();
```